# EditMode in DataGrid with single click via XAML triggers

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have DataGrid, if I want edit value in cell I must perform double click for on this and cursor appear here (with one click it just select appropriate cell)..!

May I make (via Xaml triggers) that with single click on cells they aren't just selected, but entered in EditMode at once and when I switch between cells with arrows they also enter in EditMode?

Here my current revised code

```
   <Page.Resources>
    <grd:LenghthToVisibility x:Key="LenghthToVisibility"/>
    <grd:StringToSystemIconConverter x:Key="StringToSystemIconConverter"/>
    <grd:booleanConverter x:Key="booleanConverter"/>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
        </Style>
      <Style x:Key="RightCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="RightAlignedCell" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#356815" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#e2fce2" />
            </Trigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </Page.Resources>
```

Thanks.

I have 2 strange errors and refresh my code above:
1) "Error 5 The attachable property 'CellStyle' was not found in type 'DataGrid'.
2) "Error 2 The tag 'DataGrid.CellStyle' does not exist in XML namespace 'schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'."

Answer (score 1):

To ignore the `DataGridCell` (focus the content) use:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

To enter EditMode in an [ElementStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.elementstyle.aspx)/[EditingElementStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.editingelementstyle.aspx) or [CellTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)/[CellEditingTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celleditingtemplate.aspx) environment set [DataGridCell.IsEditing Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcell.isediting.aspx) to true if selected:

```
<Style x:Key="RightAlignedCell" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    ...
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
            ...
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason I have next error, "Error 5 The attachable property 'CellStyle' was not found in type 'DataGrid'. 
"

Comment: Maybe a Typo in your XAML like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360692/xaml-the-attachable-property-columns-was-not-found-in-type-datagrid)?

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea where I can put wrong slash I try experiment, but without success. But I have during the compilation next error which I didn't behold earlier: "Error 2 The tag 'DataGrid.CellStyle' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'."

Comment: im finding that I cant even select the cell.