# Single click edit on WPF datagrid , combobox template column

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have  agrid which has three columns :

1. Friendly Name
2. Continent Name
3. Country Name

The 1st column is a textbox column Editable. The second column is a Combobox that displays the list of continents. The 3rd column is a combobox which displays list of countries based on the continent selected in the 2nd column. I want to implement single click for these column. I tried the solution given in this link
[Single click edit in WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426765/single-click-edit-in-wpf-datagrid)

But that only works on the first column and not the other two (DataGridTemplateColumn) columns.

How is this possible. Please suggest. The sample XAML and data description is given below.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GeographyData,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyleNormal}">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Friendly name" Binding="{Binding Path=FriendlyName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                <!--FilterDef -->
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*"
                                                        Header="Continents">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding ContinentId, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                      SelectedValuePath="ID"
                                                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ContinentsAndCountries,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock>
                                               <TextBlock.Text>
                                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ContinentCaptionConverter}">
                                                          <Binding Path="ContinentId"/>
                                                          <Binding Path="DataContext.ContinentsAndCountries" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}"/>
                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                </TextBlock.Text>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <!--Level-->
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*"
                                                        Header="Countries">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding CountryId, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                      SelectedValuePath="ID"
                                                      DisplayMemberPath="Name">
                                                <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CountryValuesConverter}">
                                                        <Binding Path="DataContext.ContinentsAndCountries" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}"/>
                                                        <Binding Path="ContinentId"/>
                                                    </MultiBinding>
                                                </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                                            </ComboBox>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock>
                                               <TextBlock.Text>
                                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CountryCaptionConverter}">
                                                            <Binding Path="DataContext.ContinentsAndCountries" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}"/>
                                                            <Binding Path="ContinentId"/>
                                                            <Binding Path="CountryId"/>
                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                </TextBlock.Text>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
```

Note : The data "ContinentsAndCountries" is an observable collection of master detail data.

- Girija

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10289858/620360) helps you.

Comment: Then take a look at [Tabbing from cell to cell does not set focus on control](http://iyalovoi.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/wpf-datagrid-tabbing-from-cell-to-cell-does-not-set-focus-on-control/).

Comment: Doesnot work. I guess it does the same thing as in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426765/single-click-edit-in-wpf-datagrid

Comment: I Did this by setting the combobox Loaded Event

    private void Combobox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender != null)
            {
                ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
                cmb.IsDropDownOpen = true;
            }
        }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Did this by setting the combobox Loaded Event

```
private void DataGridComboboxTemplate_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null)
        {
            ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
            cmb.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for he necro; I've finally figured out how to make a truly single-click UX. You have to intercept the DataGridCell's OnGotFocus event, set the cell's mode to IsEditing, then intercept the Loaded event for the actor control in your *CellEditingTemplate*:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style
        x:Key="AutoEditModeOnClick"
        TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">

        <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="DataGridCell_OnGotFocus" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn
        CellStyle="{StaticResource AutoEditModeOnClick}"
        Header="Score">

        <!-- Example with ComboBox -->

        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Some more XAML -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Some more XAML -->
                <ComboBox
                    DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                    SelectedValuePath="RecordID"
                    SelectedValue="{Binding Score,
                        TargetNullValue=0,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ScoreOptions,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                            AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                    Loaded="Combobox_Loaded"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn
        CellStyle="{StaticResource AutoEditModeOnClick}"
        Header="Comment">

        <!-- Example with TextBox -->

        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Some more XAML -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Some more XAML -->
                <TextBox
                    Loaded="TextBox_Loaded"
                    Text="{Binding Comment,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

In your code-behind, you need three handlers; one for the cell, and one for each type of control (ComboBox, TextBox):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Skips the 'DataGridCell.Focus' step and goes straight into IsEditing
    /// </summary>
    private void DataGridCell_OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        cell.IsEditing = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Skips the 'IsEditing' step and goes straight into IsDropDownOpen
    /// </summary>
    private void Combobox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Skips the 'IsEditing' step and goes straight into Focus
    /// </summary>
    private void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        textBox.Focus();
    }
```