# How to set focus to selected cell of WPF datagrid by single-click?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am using WPFDataGrid control and  want to set keyboard focus to selected `Cell` by single-click.By deafault user must double-click cell to start writing.i've tried the code be:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="DataGridCellStyle">
   <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
   <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True" />    
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

When i click on a cell,it get to `Editmode`,and i need to click again to set keyboard focus there and start writing!

Comment: do you need xaml-only solution?

Comment: yes,it would be great,but i can use code behind too.

Comment: you can process mouse click event and then use VisualTreeHelper.HitTest method. Then traverse visual tree up to DataGridCell and do what you need. Bring focus to it, set is as Selected and so on.

Comment: I dont know how to bring focus to it?!!should i access to it's textbox?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288323/editmode-in-datagrid-with-single-click-via-xaml-triggers

Comment: @  Ron :i've tried this,it just get cell to EditMode,i need Keyboard focus!

Comment: @raha http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.setfocusedelement.aspx

Comment: @raha, Did you checked my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I 'm not sure if this a nice feature. You might not be able to select multiple cells. anyway handle `OnCurrentCellChanged` event

```
void DG1_OnCurrentCellChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg=(Datagrid)sender;
    dg.BeginEdit();
}
```

`BeginEdit()` cause DataGridPreparingCellForEdit event to occure, I think you should handle that event:

```
private void dg_PreparingCellForEdit(object sender,  DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
{
TextBox tb = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
if (tb != null)
   {
       tb.Focus();
       //you can set caret position and ...
   }
}
```

also, you can handle BeginningEdit event.

Comment: @ Ron : thanks but it doesn't work,I need the keyboard Focus on the `TextBox`!Did you check it yourself?

Comment: @raha, I editted my answer. see if it helps. (and I think you should not put space between @ and the names)

Comment: thanks alot,but i don't know hoe to bind `PreparingCellForEdit`,because i'm using MVVM?!(and i must access `Textbox` for some other reasons like SelectAll)

Comment: @ Ron :thanks alot,but i must bind PreparingCellForEdit,and don't know how to bind it!(and i must access Textbox for some other reasons like SelectAll)

Comment: you want to handle this event? it is similar to when you handle any event: e.g `dg.PreparingCellForEdit += dg_PreparingCellForEdit`

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466889/how-to-know-while-user-editing-the-wpf-datagrid-cell-is-empty/13467131#13467131. this might help too.

Comment: Sorry, I think I cannot help you. Maybe you should ask another question.